# HTML/CSS: centering the div which radiobutton is checked

Tags: html, css

I have parent div and three child divs. I would like to position one of these child divs to the center of the browser window.

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%">
  <div id="round1" style="display: inline-block"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt1" />1</div>
  <div id="round2" style="display: inline-block"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt2" />2</div>
  <div id="round3" style="display: inline-block"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt3" />3</div>
</div>
```

What kind of CSS code is needed if I want to horizontally center the div which radiobutton is checked? No JavaScript/jQuery allowed this time.

If the radiobutton opt1 is checked, the screen should look like this:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|        (*)1(*)2(*)3|
|                    |
----------------------
```

If the radiobutton opt2 is checked, the screen should look like this:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|    (*)1(*)2(*)3    |
|                    |
----------------------
```

If the radiobutton opt3 is checked, the screen should look like this:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|(*)1(*)2(*)3        |
|                    |
----------------------
```

(*) = radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `text-align`

```
#input0:checked ~ #parent0{
  text-align: right; /*center | left*/
}
#input1:checked ~ #parent1{
  text-align: right; /*center | left*/
}
#input2:checked ~ #parent2{
  text-align: right; /*center | left*/
}
```

`html` would be something like this

```
<input id="input0">
<div id="parent0">123</div>
<input id="input1">
<div id="parent1">123</div>
<input id="input2">
<div id="parent2">123</div>
```

however you have the inputs inside a parent and in css the style is applied from top to bottom. Will only be possible with JS

Comment: Is there a demo somewhere?